# I want to get the new ID when new record is created using web API and angular resource

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I am using Web API and Angular Resource to manage my application..
When Using the Save method in my controller I want to receive the new saved record ID...

My web API method returns the new ID in the response Created Message.. But I am unable to read it...

here is my service:

```
'use strict';
appServices.factory('projectsService', function ($resource, ngAuthSettings) {
    var serviceBase = ngAuthSettings.apiServiceBaseUri;
    return $resource(serviceBase + '/api/project/:id', {}, {
        get: { method: 'GET', params: { id: '' }, isArray: true },
        getById: { method: 'GET', params: { id: '0' }, isArray: false },
        save: { method: 'POST' ,isArray: false},
        update: { method: 'PUT' },
        remove: { method: 'DELETE' }
    });
});
```

and here is my controller method:

```
 $scope.save = function ($event) {

        $event.preventDefault();

        $('#AddProjectForm').parsley().validate();
        if ($('#AddProjectForm').parsley().isValid() ) {
//HEre is my save method
            projectsService.save($scope.project).$promise.then(function (newid) {
    $location.path('/project/' + newid);
         },
             function (response) {

                 $scope.message = "Failed to register user due to:" + errors.join(' ');
             });
        }
    };
```

and In my web API this is the return

```
HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, projectRepository.NewID);
                return response;
```

Any Idea??

Comment: Just a note: get rid of jQuery. It's really messing you up. You should never, ever have DOM references in a controller, and with angular, you probably never need to use a DOM selector at all. It looks like you need to be using angular's form/validation here. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Comment: Thanks for the comment,, the JQuery I am using is for Parsley valdiation.. it gives away much better easy validiation than angualr... I wish I could find any better angular validation... it even helps with ajax validation as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely being passed back a json object from your api. So, newid is probably an json object.  Try updating this line:

```
$location.path('/project/' + newid);
```

to

```
$location.path('/project/' + newid.id);
```

Also, make sure your api is really passing back the id in the response and check what the property name is of the id field if the above line doesn't work for you.

**Update:**

Try updating your web.api response function so it looks like this:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, new { projectRepository.NewID });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response,,, can you send me away how to pass json object back with the response??  THe Object is already returning the ID as a loose value by returning the following : HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, projectRepository.NewID);
                return response;

the projectRepository.NewID holds back the new ID for the saved object.. how to put it in ajax object I Really don't know :D

Comment: I figure out somehting,,  it returns an array of the new id,, like this : if the id is 34,, it reurns {'3','4'}... or if I return a string like "test",, it returns {'t','e','s','t'},, so after all I am passing the wrong value to the response,, how to pass the righ value???

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer.  Make the suggested modification to your web.api and let me know how it works for you.

Comment: Did you get your problem figured out? Let me know if you need any other help.